# How to resolve the error: There are 0 NebulaGraph Analytics available?

Tags: nebula-graph

When I used NebulaGraph Explorer, I expected to use workflow, but the task was executed with this error.

```
There are 0 NebulaGraph Analytics available. clusterSize should be less than or equal to it
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check according to the following procedure:

Check whether the configuration of SSH password-free login between nodes is successful. You can run the ssh <user_name>@<node_ip> command on the Dag Controller machine to check whether the login succeeds.

Note that if the Dag Controller and Analytics are on the same machine, you also need to configure SSH password-free login.

Check the configuration file of the Dag Controller.

Check whether the SSH user in etc/dag-ctrl-api.yaml is the same as the user who starts the Dag Controller service and configs SSH password-free login.
Check whether the algorithm path in etc/tasks.yaml is correct.
Check whether Hadoop and Java paths in scripts/set_env.sh are correct.
Restart the Dag Controller for the settings to take effect.